# Reload puppet on change of network configuration

Tags: dhcp, puppet, startup, fqdn

We are using puppet version 2.7.11 on a debian client with autostart enabled (`START=yes` in `/etc/default/puppet`). We connect to the puppetmaster using a certificate with the FQDN (`dummyclient.work-network.pri`) and it works fine. The altered `/etc/default/puppet` file is shipped to our client, for example.

The problem is: After a restart we see a new certificate request by `dummyclient` which our puppetmaster considers as a completely different machine. One reason for this seems to be that we are using DHCP for our client names and ip addresses and the network may not yet be fully there when `puppet-agent` is started. (In our syslog `puppet-agent` is started before `NetworkManager` gives information about the nameserver and domain name.) As a further proof `hostname -f` is also empty during boot (whereas `hostname -s` gives the correct answer).

Apparently, the running puppet process does not ever update this information no matter how long the system runs. (Manually started puppet runs use the FQDN.)

Is it possible to delay the time puppet is being started or alternatively trigger a puppet restart whenever the network information changes. (E.g. when the client has been started without a network connection at all.)

Or would the optimal solution simply be to hardcode the FQDN in the client’s `/etc/hosts` file? (But then again, this should be the job of our DHCP server, no?)

Comment: I wouldn't use NetworkManager at all on a server.

Comment: Those are mainly desktop PCs and workstations and we don’t want to interfere too much with what comes with the distribution default. Sorry, I didn’t make that any clearer.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible to change the order in which services are started on boot. See [www.debian.org](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_the_configuration_of_the_runlevel) for information about how runlevel works and how to change the order in which startup scripts are run.

If you want to have puppet restart whenever you get a new dhcp lease, you could put in a cron job that periodically checks for new dhcp leases in /var/lib/dhcp.leases and does a restart when there's a change.

Comment: I’d rather find this update functionality inside puppet itself than to change order or running scripts, though. I’m guessing there must be a reason the debian package provides `rc2.d/S21puppet`.